# How to find the value of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{3n-5}{n(n^2-1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I calculate the sum of this series :

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{3n-5}{n(n^2-1)}=?$$

I've tried to divide in factors $\frac{3n-5}{n(n^2-1)}$ and obtained $\frac{-5}{n(n-1)}+\frac{8}{(n-1)(n+1)}$. But when I try to expand the series I cannot make any simplifications. Can you please help me ? I've tried to divide in factors in different ways, but also got nothing. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: Ok, I understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split it one step further as follows:
$$
\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n},\qquad \frac{1}{(n-1)(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right]
$$
Now both series telescope.

Answer (score 2):

Using partial fractions, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{3n-5}{(n-1)n(n+1)}
&=\frac{-1}{n-1}+\frac5n+\frac{-4}{n+1}\\
&=-\left(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n\right)+4\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Now sum two [Telescoping Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{-5}{n(n-1)}+\frac{8}{(n-1)(n+1)}=-5(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n})+4(\frac{1}{(n-1)}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$$